# How can I create a measured record type without a measure in F#

Tags: f#, interop, records, units-of-measurement

I have defined a record type with a unit of measure in a common library (LibRoot) that is used by both C# (LibC) and F# (LibF) code.

I then wrote a public API in the C# library (LibC) that the F# library (LibF) consumes. But any time i attempt to pass an object to this API F# complains that it must have a unit of measure.

```
//LibRoot - F#
type Vec2<[Measure] 'u> = {
    X : int
    Y : int
}
```

```
//LibC - C#
public static class Funcs
{
    public void DoWork(Vec2 vec) { //no measure needed in C#
        ....
    }
}
```

```
//LibF - F#

open LibC
let myVec : Vec2<1> = { X = 123; Y = 456 }
DoWork(myVec) //FS0001
```

**error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a    'Vec2'    but given a    'Vec2<1>'    The tuples have
differing lengths of 0 and 1**

I've tried:

- `Vec2<1>` : FS0001
- `Vec2<0>` : Invalid Literal in type
- `Vec2<()>` : Unexpected ')' in type
- `Vec2<_>` : FS0001
- `Vec2<unit>` : Expected unit of measure, not type
- `(Vec2) myVec` : No constructors available for type 'Vec2<'u>

**Does anybody know a way to construct a measured record type in an interop friendly way?**

Comment: Probably can't be done, units of measure info is essentially lost after compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, units of measure are F#-only feature that has no representation in the compiled .NET code, so when you use a unit-annotated type from C#, it will appear as a type without units.

The compiled C# code will not contain special F# meta-data to indicate that this is a unit-annotated type and so the F# compiler referencing your C# library does not recognise it as unit-annotated type. Arguably, the F# compiler could be smarter and figure this out (because it can figure out that the `Vec2` type is originally coming from F#).

I don't think there is a safe way of converting un-measured `Vec2` to measured `Vec2<_>` but the unsafe conversion using `unbox` will work at runtime:

```
let v : LibRoot.Vec2<1> = { LibRoot.Vec2.X = 1; Y = 2 }
LibCs.Funcs.DoWork(unbox v)
```

I don't think there is a way of referring to the type `Vec2` (without measure) explicitly in F# code, but `unbox` infers the type fine. This is not very nice, so if you need this conversion often, it's probably better to redesign your library so that C# uses a separate type without units.

Answer (score 1):

Tomas' answer is correct. I'll share my workaround for posterity.

My measure units were

```
 [<Measure>] type Absolute
 [<Measure>] type Relative
```

I introduced 'concrete' record types that were convertible to `Vec2<>` for interop. For example

```
type Offset2 = { 
   X : int
   Y : int 
}
   with 
       static member ofVec (vec : Vec2<Relative>) : Offset2 = { X = vec.X; Y = vec.Y }
       static member toVec (off: Offset2) : Vec2<Relative> = { X = off.X; Y = off.Y }
```

I convert them into Vec2's to perform math and but use the 'concrete' types for public APIs. It is a little annoying to have the extra types but it works.